# How do I expedite this Excel VBA macro?

Tags: excel, vba

I know a little bit of VBA but I am always looking for smarter ways (the ways you people work!!).

Here is what I am trying to do. I have to deal with some data that has

Year | Month | Day | Hour | Minute | Data1 | Data2.... | DataN

each in a separate column and has thousands of rows. The number of "Data" columns is defined by the user during the run time (at least 1 and max 100). The data may have any time step eg every minute, 5 mins, 10 mins, each hour, daily and so on. The user then specifies the output data interval which will be always greater than input data interval.

So, this macro is supposed to write the data in the interval specified by the user. The data in each column in between the output time step has to be added togther. See following two tables:

Input:

```
Yr     Mth  Day Hr  Min Data_1  Data_2

2010    2   7   8   0   1.01    2.01

2010    2   7   8   5   1.02    2.02

2010    2   7   8   10  1.03    2.03

2010    2   7   8   15  1.04    2.04

2010    2   7   8   20  1.05    2.05

2010    2   7   8   25  1.06    2.06

2010    2   7   8   30  1.07    2.07

2010    2   7   8   35  1.08    2.08

2010    2   7   8   40  1.09    2.09

2010    2   7   8   45  1.10    2.10

2010    2   7   8   50  1.11    2.11

2010    2   7   8   55  1.12    2.12

2010    2   7   9   0   1.13    2.13

2010    2   7   9   5   1.14    2.14
```

Output:

```
Yr     Mth  Day Hr  Min Data_1  Data_2

2010    2   7   8   0   1.01    2.01

2010    2   7   8   15  3.09    6.09

2010    2   7   8   30  3.18    6.18

2010    2   7   8   45  3.27    6.27

2010    2   7   9   0   3.36    6.36
```

So, the input data is every 5 minute and the output data has to be every 15 minute. Each row of data between successive 15 minutes interval have to be added together.

I have this thing working as I use two loops traversing horizontally and vertically and writing the values to the spreadsheet at each step. But it is really slow.

Any help to expedite this process will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

-MP

**** Code I have been using to write the processed data to a text file:

```
Open FName For Output Access Write As #FNum
For RowNdx = StartRow To endrow
done = Int((RowNdx / endrow) * 100)
Application.StatusBar = "Exporting *.gag file... (" & done & " % done )"
    WholeLine = ""
    For colNdx = StartCol To Endcol
        If Sheets("Output").Cells(RowNdx, colNdx).Text = "" Then
            CellValue = ""
        Else
           CellValue = Sheets("Output").Cells(RowNdx, colNdx).Text
        End If
        WholeLine = WholeLine & CellValue & sep
    Next colNdx
    WholeLine = Left(WholeLine, Len(WholeLine) - Len(sep))
    Print #FNum, WholeLine
Next RowNdx
Close #FNum
```

Is there a way to write a range to a text file at once. I am trying to avoid looping.

Thanks for your help

MPD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried setting

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
```

before your loops?

Remember to set

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

after your loops have completed.

You might also save all of your data to an array in your loops and then writing the entire array as a range to your output spreadsheet, instead of writing the values cell-by-cell, which is what it seems like you are doing now.

Comment: Hi PaulR, thanks for your response. I had screenupdating turned off but I had not tried 

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

I will give that a try. Yeah, right now I am writing cell-to-cell. I thought of storing all the data to array and write at the end, but the problem is I won't know how many data columns will be there until runtime, so I wonn't know how many arrays to initiate. Any thought?

Comment: If the data is arranged by column, you could get the column count with Worksheets("YourWorksheetName").UsedRange.Columns.Count and then set your array size to that length.   It works the same for rows, too, just use Worksheets("YourWorksheetName").UsedRange.Rows.Count.

Comment: Thanks PaulR. I ended up using ranges instead of looping through each cell. This is expedited the process a lot. It takes about 4 minutes to process a data using my old code and now it is done in about 40 sec. I need to export the processed data to a text file and that is taking the logest time. Is there a way to export a range to a text file directly (instead of writing each line)? I am trying to post my code here but it formats the code badly. So, I have inserted the code that I have been using to write to a text file at the end of my original post.
Thanks for you help

Comment: If you want to save a range to a file as a different format, you might copy the range over to a "scratch" worksheet, and then save that "scratch" worksheet as a text file. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.saveas(v=vs.80).aspx , here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlfileformat.aspx and here http://www.mrexcel.com/archive/Controls/19982.html for hints on how to do this. Hope it helps!

Comment: PaulR,

Thanks a lot for such quick reply!

I in fact tried doing that. But the problem with it is when I save the sheet to a .txt file, my workbook name is changed to *.txt. I could resave the workbook as *.xls at the end but it prompts me if I want to replace existing file. 

I wonder if there is a way to either 

- prevent my workbook from being renamed to *.txt and just export the scratch sheet as *.txt or 

- disable "replace existing file" prompt while saving the book back to *.xls

Comment: Ah. You might try SaveCopyAs.  I've never had my workbook nuked by using SaveAs (I have killed a few using Save!), but you could be safe and call SaveCopyAs.

Comment: SaveCopyAs just allows creating a copy of XlNormal file. I ended up copying the output data to a new workbook, saved this workbook as a .txt file and closed it. I still kept the old code (saving each line) and set up the macro such that for smaller data, I still use line by line and for bulky data, I will use copy to another workbook. Thanks for all your help!!